# Добавление в таблицу всех строк из вывода python

Tags: python, prettytable

Пытаюсь делать выборку по файлу excel

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file, read_only=True)
ws = wb.active

mytable = PrettyTable(['None'])

for row in ws.iter_rows():
    for cell in row:
        if cell.value == "x":
            value = ws.cell(row=cell.row, column=1).value
            value2 = ws.cell(row=cell.row, column=2).value
            if value2 == None:
                print(value)
            else:
                print(value, value2)
```

На вывод у меня выходит список значений:

```
Яблоко
Банан
Клубника
```

При внесении этих данных в prettytable, сохраняется только последнее значение из списка:

```
+----------+
|   None   |
+----------+
| Клубника |
+----------+
```

Как добавить все значения сразу?

Comment: чем вас `x.add_row` не устраивает вместо вместе с `print`?

Comment: @Сергей add_row() только последнее значение регистрирует, не все, в примере привёл

Comment: что, если раз за разом проводить запись `value`, то она затирает последнюю и пишет на её место?

Comment: @Сергей с помощью print() я сравниваю, что выдаёт pretty table, и как оно на самом деле есть. Мне нужно записать все строчки в таблицу, которые выдаёт алгоритм, но записывает только последнюю

Comment: повторю вопрос: "что, если раз за разом проводить запись `value`, то она затирает последнюю и пишет на её место?" (новое значение) Например, в цикле `for cell in row` сначала записала "Яблоко", а затем его затерла и записала "Банан"? (это очень-очень странное поведение для команды типа `add`)